# Does restarting Fragment also recall FirebaseDatabase

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database

I have 3 fragments and a bottom navigation menu to switch between them.
In every fragment i have a recyclerview to display data gathered from FirebaseDatabase.

My question is: Should i use `Replace()` fragment? As it would result in restarting the fragment and requesting again Firebase `SingleEventValue` every time the user navigate between fragments

Or i must use `Add` `Show` `Hide`? Or that would lead in memory leaks?

Answer (score 0):

The methods you use to deal with the fragments are mostly not relevant.  The Firebase SDK will cache data previously fetched, so if you make a second request for some data, from any point in your app, you will be seeing cached data, and it will even work offline.  There are no "leaks" involved here when using single value events.

Adding a listener to a database location is a different matter.  Ideally, listeners should be attached when a fragment becomes visible, then detached when not visible.

Comment: I am sorry i am still a beginner. I didnt fully understand, calling firebase database ```addListenerForSingleValueEvent``` would cache its data? And also what method do you suggest for switching between fragments ```show``` ```hide``` or simply replace?